# How to compare two colors?

Tags: css, colors

On my web project I've a list of almost twenty different colors.

How can I compare each of these colors to know how much this one is darker, more saturated, greener... than an other ?

My aim is to use these calculated values with Less functions.

Comment: @leigero I accept JavaScript/PHP/Java/C/C++/Python or just algorithmics solutions

Comment: It's for the development, it's not a future functionnality of the website (but you're right, it could be interresting to create a web-service for it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the distance between colours using them as 3D vectors.
The contents of the vectors can be the R, G and B components or H, S and V components (or any other classification you can think of).

Now let the distance `d(c1, c2)` be the distance calculated between colours `c1` and `c2`:

```
d(c1, c2) = sqrt((c1_1 - c2_1)^2 + (c1_2 - c2_2)^2 + (c1_3 - c2_3)^2)
```

You might recognize this as the [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance). Any other [norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29) will do.

Comment: But this didn't tell me which value (hue, saturation, luminance) to increase/decrease to go from a color to another isn't it?

Comment: No, but that is very specific, and maybe even impossible. You might be able to define the angle between two colors, just like two vectors have an angle in 3D space. That tells you which direction to go from one colour to another.